# GLSL - Sample an volume of 3d texture

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures

I'm recently working with 3d textures in OpenGL.
I realized that when you are working with 3d textures, you have to use texture3d() A LOT.
Which is pretty much a gpu killer. Is there any function in glsl that allows me to sample an VOLUME of 3d texture? So, instead of calling texture3D() 32768 times, I can do something like this:

```
texture3DVolume(3dtexture, vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), vec3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2));
```

Which samples at 0.5 0.5 0.5, an volume of 0.2 0.2 0.2.

Comment: What are you doing in your fragment shader that it would be at all reasonable to access a texture 2^15th times? What are you going to do in a single execution of a fragment shader with that much information?

Comment: What would you expect the result of this sample to be? An average of all values in that volume, the median, sum, ... ?

Comment: Nicol Bolas: For ex. I want to sample the hemisphere above some point.

Answer (score 0):

No : this would involve, as you noticed it yourself, sampling all the volume.

In 2D you can use Summed Area Tables. It enables you to compute the sum of all the values of a matrix inside a "box" with only 4 samples; I guess the concept extends to 3D easily.

Note that you will have a pretty expensive preprocessing step; and you can only have the mean and the sum, no other fancy stuff like geometric mean or median.

Here are some explanations from AMD on a different use-case : http://developer.amd.com/media/gpu_assets/GDC2005_SATEnvironmentReflections.pdf

I guess you could also use mipmaps : to sample a 2x2x2 volume, sample the 1rst mipmap... but this won't work out of the box for arbitrary sample locations.

Comment: I doubt that a 3D version of Summed Area Tables would be a practical solution. With 2D SATs you (usually**) have to allow for the worst case range for the summed values, so for a monochrome source 512x512 8bpp texture, each stored value in the SAT would need an additional 18b, giving 26b per entry! For a, say, 3D, 8bpp 256^3 texture, you'd need 8+3x8=> 32bpp.  It'd be 3x worse for an RGB texture. 
[**There are work arounds for this but they aren't pretty.]

Comment: I'd be interested to know more about the non-pretty workarounds... any ref ?

Comment: Well, Crow's original paper [link](http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps160/Fall05/papers/p207-crow.pdf) had some suggestions but maybe the most recent advances are in "Fast Summed-Area Table Generation and its Applications" by Hensley et al, who use offset floating point to keep the values from exploding. Not sure if the potential loss of precision is an issue or not.

Comment: Thanks for the links ! I actually find the workaround very clever and elegant. But 8 bits is definitely not enough, and 16 isn't probably either.